# Path.Data styling works only on first instance of styled object

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, styles

A have a ListBox of items, every ListBoxItem contains an icon in the form of a `Path` object, like so:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ...>
            ...
            <Path Margin="4" Style="{StaticResource ErrorIconPath}" 
                  Stretch="Uniform" Width="26" Height="26"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                  UseLayoutRounding="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The Path's style is contained in `Appl.xaml` (`Application.Resources` section) and is the following:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorIconPath" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1M874.094,289.369L854.3,254.63C854.028,254.151 853.515,253.856 852.958,253.856 852.403,253.856 851.89,254.151 851.617,254.63L831.824,289.369C831.555,289.84 831.559,290.416 831.835,290.883 832.111,291.348 832.618,291.634 833.165,291.634L872.752,291.634C873.299,291.634 873.805,291.348 874.081,290.883 874.357,290.416 874.361,289.84 874.094,289.369 M855.653,287.189L850.264,287.189 850.264,282.745 855.653,282.745 855.653,287.189z M855.653,279.41L850.264,279.41 850.264,266.077 855.653,266.077 855.653,279.41z" />
</Style>
```

The trouble is that only the first item in the ListBox binds the `Data` property as expected, the other ones don't bind it at all (hence they appear as blank space, but match the size of the `Path`). Also when I use the style anywhere else (i.e. outside the ListBox), only the first instance that occurs will bind.

The weird thing is that if I define for example the `Fill` property in the `Style` instead of inline, it works just fine and doesn't exibit the same problems as the `Path` property.

My guess is that is has something to do with `Data` not being a primitive type, but I haven't found any fixes.

EDIT: Interestingly, when I bind the `Data` property directly to `System.String` resource, it works. I would still like to be able to define this property via a Style though.

EDIT 2: I've just came across the same issue in WPF, when setting Path to a Content of a Button via a Style that is used across more buttons. The path shows up in just one buttons, the others are blank.

Answer (score 7):

Path.Fill is a DependencyProperty, while Path.Data isn't. Instead do:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid ...>
        ...
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource MyPath}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

`ContentPresenter.Content` is a DependencyProperty so this should work:

```
<Path x:Key="MyPath" Margin="4" Style="{StaticResource ErrorIconPath}" 
      Stretch="Uniform" Width="26" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
      UseLayoutRounding="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Data="F1M874.094,289.369L854.3,254.63C854.028,254.151 853.515,253.856 852.958,253.856 852.403,253.856 851.89,254.151 851.617,254.63L831.824,289.369C831.555,289.84 831.559,290.416 831.835,290.883 832.111,291.348 832.618,291.634 833.165,291.634L872.752,291.634C873.299,291.634 873.805,291.348 874.081,290.883 874.357,290.416 874.361,289.84 874.094,289.369 M855.653,287.189L850.264,287.189 850.264,282.745 855.653,282.745 855.653,287.189z M855.653,279.41L850.264,279.41 850.264,266.077 855.653,266.077 855.653,279.41z"/>
```

Comment: But that way I loose the option to set Path-specific properties inline, which I need to do (for example the Fill property is set dynamically)

Comment: I'm confused by your requirments. Let's rewind and start with the ItemsControl (your ListBox). It has a bunch of Items (that derive from object). They are probably strongly typed. You have an item of type ErrorItem, that should have a DataTemplate that displays an ErrorIcon path. All the other items presumably have different DataTemplates that display valid information, each of which has a different fill color for w/e path. But you are setting the ItemTemplate property, which I interpret as "all the Items in my ListBox are error items that need to be displayed this particular way.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but here goes: You are right, that not all items in my ItemsContainer are errors, they are either "info", "warning" or "error". The reason I decided to go with a single Template is that the items are differentiated only by the Fill property of the icon - black for info (not visible), yellow for warning and red for error. This is why I need to access to the Path's Fill property where I bind it.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx) cannot be shared. Have you tried setting the [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)`= "false"` to:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorIconPath" TargetType="Path">
```

Comment: Outstanding! Exactly what i need! ;)

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of the x:Shared!

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same behavior in Silverlight and asked a similar question here on StackOverflow.com
 ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/13426198/1796930), but as I'm writing this, it's been 1 month and I've yet to get even a single answer.

However, as you mentioned in your first edit, I too was able to perform a workaround by creating a resource with my geometry data as a string and then binding the `Data` property of the `Path` objects to the string resource resource.

I also had to create two instances of the `Path` objects that were identical other than each one using a different resource (i.e. two different icons) and then binding the visibility of each to a property in my ViewModel to display the appropriate one.

Comment: The link to stack question is broken.

Answer (score 2):

I am very sure that you did not forgot the stroke here in Path style

```
<Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
```

I have tested you code on my machine , it worked fine if above line added in style

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work. You don't need the Stroke property to be set, the Fill property should do.

Comment: Yes I did, I just haven't included it in my sample (it was done via binding and a converter and I wanted to make the sample as clear as possible).

Answer (score 1):

My first tought was your Path would be broken or not valid. But then I saw you are using the Syncfusion Metro Studio. I tried it with exactly the same code you have and it worked very well. In a Data Template of 5 Items or as a single Path Item.

Have you tried to set the Fill statically to Red or something?

Also maybe try this for the Style definition

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorIconPath" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
```

Third suggestion would be to move the style definition from the App to your Page or even to your Control itself.

To be sure there will be no default styles applied, try

```
OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
```

Hope this helps :)